# Import package from PYPI

Tags: python, python-import, pypi

I use the "pip install xxx" from PYPI (https://pypi.python.org/pypi). Then I type "import xxx", it can import package without any problem.

However, when I uploaded my package to PYPI, Then I type "import xxx", it cannot import package. It said "ImportError, no module named xxx".

I think it is because the package is not my current directory? If yes, how should I do to avoid this problem when I uploaded my package to PYPI? Thanks.

Comment: Can you correct the typos please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your package does not contain any (valid) Python packages. Python package by definition has to have a `__init__.py`. Just put an empty `__init__.py` inside the `mypackagemx3292016` folder.

I would however suggest not to use a package but rather just a single module. A package works good when you need to group multiple modules together. A [simple example from distutils docs](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/introduction.html#distutils-simple-example) shows how to list individual modules.

In terms of installation you need to do exactly the same as with any other package:

```
pip install mypackagemx3292016
```

If you want to avoid the hassle of having to do this every time you upload a new version to pypi, you can symlink the local copy:

```
pip install -e /path/to/mypackagemx3292016
```

If that does not work there is probably a problem with your `setup.py`.

Comment: Thanks. But I do not think you answer my questions

Comment: If you uploaded it to pypy why not just give a link to the real package so we can help you? It's public anyway.

Comment: Thanks. If you could help me solve this problem, it will be great.

Comment: Thanks for your update. It works for me now. I can import package without any problem. After I "import mypackagemx3292016", how I call ''mypackage.py" ?